# Can ping facebook but not access

Tags: google-chrome, ping, facebook, ipconfig

I live in Canada, and run a windows 8.1 laptop, primarily using Google Chrome version 35.0.1916.153 m.

Within the past week, I find myself no longer able to access www.facebook.com with my laptop...

- I can access facebook with other computers, on the same network at home, or different networks.
- On my home network with my laptop, I can access the internet, including secure websites (Apple ID, Gmail) and this works for both Internet Explorer and Google Chrome.
- Within the command console i can ping www.facebook.com and what I get you can read below..
- I have tried ipconfig /flushdns and on one occasion it had an immediate effect to restore access to www.facebook.com however the other 3 or 4 times I've tried it still yields "the webpage is not available".
- I can't access anything Facebook server related, Facebook help pages, etc.
- I've verified in Google chrome's advanced settings page under Network/Internet Properties/Connections/LAN Settings that "use a proxy server for your LAN" is NOT checked, the only checked item in this window is "Automatically Detect Settings"
- I read on another page that you can try accessing Facebook by typing in the actual server IP address provided via the pinging info gathered in console I tried loading in Chrome "star.c10r.facebok.com" but Chrome responds saying "Oops! Google Chrome could not find 'www.c10r.facebook.com"   - I'm no expert with computers but to me that IP address does not look appropriate at all and I'm wondering if the source of this problem is malware. I'm currently using AVG 2014's free edition and SpyBot Search&Destroy for security and have run scans since the issue began but did not find anything of note.
- Anyone have any suggestions please? This is so frustrating and I'm not sure what further I can do.

---

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 6.3.9600]
(c) 2013 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

C:\Users\ryanjames>ipconfig

Windows IP Configuration


Wireless LAN adapter Local Area Connection* 12:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :

Ethernet adapter Bluetooth Network Connection:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :

Ethernet adapter Ethernet:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :

Wireless LAN adapter Wi-Fi:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   IPv6 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 2002:627c:3691:0:49e8:70c2:c708:e6f0
   Temporary IPv6 Address. . . . . . : 2002:627c:3691:0:19ed:1725:6ab3:6a4f
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::49e8:70c2:c708:e6f0%3
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.137
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : fe80::c2c1:c0ff:fe51:bb8b%3
                                       192.168.1.1

Tunnel adapter Local Area Connection* 2:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   IPv6 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 2001:0:9d38:90d7:145b:e09:9d83:c96e
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::145b:e09:9d83:c96e%7
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . :

Tunnel adapter isatap.{BE414588-451F-4093-A369-AE48849E3E93}:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :

C:\Users\ryanjames>ping www.facebook.com

Pinging star.c10r.facebook.com [2a03:2880:f003:801:face:b00c:0:1] with 32 bytes
of data:
Reply from 2a03:2880:f003:801:face:b00c:0:1: time=179ms
Reply from 2a03:2880:f003:801:face:b00c:0:1: time=152ms
Reply from 2a03:2880:f003:801:face:b00c:0:1: time=146ms
Reply from 2a03:2880:f003:801:face:b00c:0:1: time=324ms

Ping statistics for 2a03:2880:f003:801:face:b00c:0:1:
    Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 4, Lost = 0 (0% loss),
Approximate round trip times in milli-seconds:
    Minimum = 146ms, Maximum = 324ms, Average = 200ms

C:\Users\ryanjames>ipconfig

Windows IP Configuration


Wireless LAN adapter Local Area Connection* 12:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :

Ethernet adapter Bluetooth Network Connection:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :

Ethernet adapter Ethernet:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :

Wireless LAN adapter Wi-Fi:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   IPv6 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 2002:627c:3691:0:49e8:70c2:c708:e6f0
   Temporary IPv6 Address. . . . . . : 2002:627c:3691:0:19ed:1725:6ab3:6a4f
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::49e8:70c2:c708:e6f0%3
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.137
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : fe80::c2c1:c0ff:fe51:bb8b%3
                                       192.168.1.1

Tunnel adapter Local Area Connection* 2:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   IPv6 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 2001:0:9d38:90d7:145b:e09:9d83:c96e
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::145b:e09:9d83:c96e%7
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . :

Tunnel adapter isatap.{BE414588-451F-4093-A369-AE48849E3E93}:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :

C:\Users\ryanjames>\ipconfig /flushdns
'\ipconfig' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

C:\Users\ryanjames>ipconfig /flushdns

Windows IP Configuration

Successfully flushed the DNS Resolver Cache.
```

---

Comment: `star.c10r.facebook.com` isn't an IP address, it's the server name that `www.facebook.com` resolves to.  The IP address your system is trying to access is `2a03:2880:f003:801:face:b00c:0:1`, which is an IPv6 address.  Do your other computers use IPv4 or IPv6?

Comment: What is the error that you get when going to Facebook (in the browser)? Also, is this a laptop from your work and they are blocking access?

Comment: Did you try with another web browser(Firefox/IE/Chrome)?

Comment: Would you please check your windows time and date?

Comment: 1- Im not sure what other computers in my house are using IPv4 or IPv6. To be honest myself and my roommates steal my neighbours wifi (dont ask me how we aquired the password it just happened/act of god/miracle). We all have full access to the internet, but only my computer is affected with the issue of not being able to access anything facebook online.

Comment: 2- There are no error messages when I try to access www.facebook.com Google chrome returns with "The webpage is not available". This is my personal laptop, not a business machine. Access is not being blocked by the network as occasionally I can get through via ipconfig /flushdns and other computers in my home do not have any issues.

Comment: 3- I tried with Internet Explorer, issue persists.

Comment: 4- my windows time and date? 2014-07-04,eastern standard time US/Canada and 8:16 is what it reads at this time...

Comment: as a further step taken, i removed (deleted) all Extensions listed in CHrome's Settings. Still the issue persists, and ipconfig /flushdns from the command prompt isn't working today at all either.

Comment: could this be a certificate issue?

Comment: update! so I was not going to give up easy tonight and tried again to tinker around, /flushdns, wasn't working, so I closed chrome, ipconfig /flushdns twice, reopened chrome, and the main facebook login page loaded! I put in my credentials and tried to further login only to get the message again "The Webpage is not available"